# Find websites returning 503 response codes

Tags: ruby, http

Where can I find pages returning 503 codes so I can test a script I'm working on?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to create a separate script that returns the status code in question. The contents of such HTTP response should be pretty straighforward:

```
HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
```

But if you are not fond of building it all by yourself then you can use **[FakeWeb](http://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb)** which is a test helper for faking responses to web requests.